# Matlab Testing a trained neural network

Tags: matlab, neural-network, classification

I have a training sample set and the according targets. The targets are 7 different classes.

```
net = patternnet(10);
[net,tr] = train(net,samples.',targets.');

%samples is 200x7 and targets is 200x1

test = net([0;1;1;1;1;0;1])
```

Now when I execute the last line I would expect test to hold the value of the class that the net classifies the input [0;1;1;1;1;0;1] as. But All I get is a weird decimal value, and not one of the values that are entered in "targets" (which are 1,2,3,4,5,6 or 7). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The `patternnet` documentation says that

> The target data for pattern recognition networks should consist of vectors of all zero values except for a 1 in element i, where i is the class they are to represent.

Thus, `targets` should be an array of the size 200x7, where 7 is the number of the classes. Each column should consist of zeros except for the i-th row, where i is the index of the class.

You can transform `targets` to the required form by using the [`ind2vec`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/ind2vec.html) function.